# How to remove the number inside the bracket?

Tags: php, regex

We know it will remove everything always inside brackets    `/\((.*?)\)/` But I need to remove the number with bracket. There is a string like    Acqua(Demon) (21). So I want to remove only (21), not (Demon) from this string. If any one knows about this type of issue. Please reply me.
Thank you

Comment: `/\(\d+\)/` Should work.

Comment: You should also consider calling trim() after removing a part of the string. Or do `/ ?\(\d+\)/`

Comment: Than you. Great. And another thing there is a pattern to write a patter match in regx. How to learn full to do a customization in regx when it is required. If there is any reference site to learn these thing, please provide me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
/\(([0-9]+?)\)/gm
```

Comment: I'm afraid the `g` modifier won't be recognized by PHP